# When Localizable.strings file's content are loaded into memory?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, localization, core-foundation

I am working on reducing memory footprint (RAM) of an iOS app. One potential area is to reduce the number of languages supported by our app as there will be multiple of `Localizable.strings` files.

My colleague has mentioned that all strings files are loaded at once (in RAM) and hence, we need to reduce the number of language supported.

I have dug deeper into `NSLocalizedString` and looks like only current locale localised string should be loaded into the memory.

If we have 100s of `Localizable.strings` files, then only current locale localised string file will be loaded. And they are loaded into heap segment of the memory.

However, if I explicitly calls the following (hypothetically), then the requested string files of that language will be loaded into `NSMutuableDictionary` (heap segment):

```
let lanArr = ["en", "hi", "es", "ar", "el", "ja", "tr", "zh-Hant"]
var index = 0

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lanArr[index], ofType: "lproj")
let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

let str = NSLocalizedString("abhi", tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
display(str)
```

Is my understanding correct?

So I don't have to be worried about too many languages supported (too many strings files) as only current localised string file is loaded into RAM?

Let's say I do explicitly call NSLocalizedString() for specific language, then old `NSMutuableDictionary` (which has string file content) won't be deallocated?

If so, then we don't have to be worried about number of languages, as space complexity will be always `O(1)` w.r.t number of languages.

Comment: strings file is a light weight file and only one language localizable file is executing when the app is launch ... 
if you are try to going against apple frame as above you are using index kinda thing rather Locale.current.languageCode e.g "en" that will give current language code of the language from app languages in settings.

Comment: That code is just a sample code that I have written to understand memory consumption and how memory increases with each call to `NSLocalizedString`.

That code is not for prod.

Comment: Okay. you just have to add languages in project and rest will handle by apple just add key and value in strings file. It doesn't matter how much language you added it will be executed with plist file or before launch the scene

Comment: My question is "Does RAM consumption of an app increases by number of Localizable.strings?" or just one `Localizable.string` file is loaded by default.

Comment: just one loaded by default if you following the right way to implement